# Python Crash Course -Alien Invasion -Game Ending Error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on the Alien Invasion project at the end of Python Crash Course 2nd Edition and I am having a problem with my game ending after the user runs out of lives. The game is supposed to end after all 3 lives are lost but when that happens for mine the aliens continue to move off the bottom of the screen. There are no error messages and from my many checks through the code I have entered it word for word from the book. I have worked up to the section where the scoreboard is added but now I am resetting the scoreboard which requires the game to end properly. Below is a copy of all the necessary code files that would apply to this issue. Each separate file is indicated by #filename.py and the code for said file follows. If there is anything else needed to check through this please let me know.

```
# Project Qapla'
# Matthew Moore
# alien_invasion.py

import sys
from time import sleep

import pygame

from settings import Settings
from game_stats import GameStats
from scoreboard import Scoreboard
from button import Button
from ship import Ship
from bullet import Bullet
from alien import Alien

class AlienInvasion:
       """Overall class to manage assets and behaviour."""
       
       def __init__(self):
           """Initialize the game, and create game resources."""
           pygame.init()
           self.settings = Settings()
           
           #Partial screen play control
           self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
               (self.settings.screen_width,self.settings.screen_height))           
           
           #Full screen play control
           #self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0,0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
           #self.settings.screen_width = self.screen.get_rect().width
           #self.settings.screen_height = self.screen.get_rect().height
                       
           pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")
           self.stats = GameStats(self)   
           self.sb = Scoreboard(self) 
           self.ship = Ship(self)
           self.bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
           self.aliens = pygame.sprite.Group()
           
           self._create_fleet()
           
           #Make the play button
           self.play_button = Button(self, "Play")
           
           
           
       def run_game(self):
           """Start the main loop for the game."""
           while True:
               self._check_events()
               
               if self.stats.game_active:
                   self.ship.update()
                   self._update_bullets()
                   self._update_aliens()
               
               self._update_screen()
               
                           
               #Make the most recently drawn screen visible.
               pygame.display.flip()
 

       def _check_events(self):
           """Respond to keypresses abd mouse events."""
           for event in pygame.event.get():
               if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                   sys.exit()
               elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                   self._check_keydown_events(event)
               elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                   self._check_keyup_events(event)
               elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                   mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                   self._check_play_button(mouse_pos)


       def _check_keydown_events(self,event):
           """Respond to key presses."""       
           if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
               self.ship.moving_right = True
           elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
               self.ship.moving_left = True
           elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
               sys.exit()
           elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
               self._fire_bullet()
                

       def _check_keyup_events(self,event):
           """Respond to key releases."""      
           if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
               self.ship.moving_right = False
           elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
               self.ship.moving_left = False
               
       def _check_play_button(self, mouse_pos):
           """Starts new game when player clicks play button"""
           button_clicked = self.play_button.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos)
           if button_clicked and not self.stats.game_active:
               #Reset the game statistics
               self.settings.initialize_dynamic_settings()
               self.stats.game_active = True
               
               #Get rid of any remaining aliens and bullets.
               self.aliens.empty()
               self.bullets.empty()
               
               #create a new fleet and center the ship
               self._create_fleet()
               self.ship.center_ship()
               
               #Hide Mouse cursor
               pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

       def _fire_bullet(self):
           """Create a new bullet and add it to the bullets group."""
           if len(self.bullets) < self.settings.bullets_allowed:
               new_bullet = Bullet(self)
               self.bullets.add(new_bullet)
            
       def _update_bullets(self):
           """Update postiion of bullets and get rid of old bullets."""
           #Update bullet positions
           self.bullets.update()
           
           #Get rid of bullets that have disappeared
           for bullet in self.bullets.copy():
               if bullet.rect.bottom <= 0:
                   self.bullets.remove(bullet)
               #print(len(self.bullets))
           
           self._check_bullet_alien_collision()
       
       def _check_bullet_alien_collision(self):
           """Responds to bullet-alien collisions"""
           #Check for any bullets that have hit aliens
           #If so, get rid of alien and bullet
           collisions = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(
               self.bullets, self.aliens, True, True)
               
           if collisions:
               self.stats.score += self.settings.alien_points
               self.sb.prep_score()
               
           if not self.aliens:
               #Destroy existing bullets and create a new fleet
               self.bullets.empty()
               self._create_fleet()
               self.settings.increase_speed()
       
       def _update_aliens(self):
           """Update the positions of all alliens in the fleet/Check if
           fleet is on an edge"""
           self._check_fleet_edges()
           self.aliens.update()
           
           #look for alien-ship collisions
           if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(self.ship, self.aliens):
               self._ship_hit()
               
           self._check_alien_bottom()
               
       def _ship_hit(self):
           """Responds to a ship being hit by an alien"""
           if self.stats.ships_left > 0:
               self.stats.ships_left -= 1
               self.aliens.empty()
               self.bullets.empty()
               self._create_fleet()
               self.ship.center_ship()
               sleep(0.5)
           else:
               self.stats.game_active_ = False
               pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)
               
       def _create_fleet(self):
           """create the fleet of aliens"""
           #create an alien and find the number of aliens in a row.
           #Spacing between each alien is equal to one alien width.
           alien = Alien(self)
           alien_width, alien_height = alien.rect.size
           avaliable_space_x = self.settings.screen_width - (2 * alien_width)
           number_aliens_x = avaliable_space_x // (2*alien_width)
           
           #determine th enumber of rows of aliens that fit on the screen
           ship_height = self.ship.rect.height
           avaliable_space_y = (self.settings.screen_height-
                                   (3*alien_height) - ship_height)
           number_rows = avaliable_space_y // (2 * alien_height)
           
           #Create the full fleet of aliens
           for row_number in range(number_rows):
               for alien_number in range(number_aliens_x):
                   self._create_alien(alien_number, row_number)
               
       def _create_alien(self, alien_number, row_number):
           #create an alien and [place it in the row
           alien =  Alien(self)
           alien_width, alien_height = alien.rect.size
           alien.x = alien_width + 2*alien_width * alien_number
           alien.rect.x = alien.x
           alien.rect.y = alien_height + 2 * alien.rect.height * row_number
           self.aliens.add(alien)
        
       def _check_fleet_edges(self):
           """Respond approprietly if any aliens have touched an edge"""
           for alien in self.aliens.sprites():
               if alien.check_edges():
                   self._change_fleet_direction()
                   break
                   
       def _check_alien_bottom(self):
           """Checks if aliens have reached the bottom of the screen"""
           screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
           for alien in self.aliens.sprites():
               if alien.rect.bottom >= screen_rect.bottom:
                   self._ship_hit()
                   break
                   #treats it the same as ship getting hit
                   
       def _change_fleet_direction(self):
           """Drop the fleet and change direction"""
           for alien in self.aliens.sprites():
               alien.rect.y += self.settings.fleet_drop_speed
           self.settings.fleet_direction *= -1
       
       def _update_screen(self):
           """Update images on the screen, and flip to the new screen."""
           # Redraw the screen during each pass
           self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
           self.ship.blitme()
           for bullet in self.bullets.sprites():
               bullet.draw_bullet() 
           self.aliens.draw(self.screen)
           #Draw the score information
           self.sb.show_score()
           #draw the button if game is inactive
           if not self.stats.game_active:
               self.play_button.draw_button()
           
           pygame.display.flip()
            
                       
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Make a game instance, and run the game.
    ai = AlienInvasion()
    ai.run_game()

#alien.py
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Alien(Sprite):
    """A class to represent a single alien in the fleet"""
    
    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        """Initialize the alien and its starting position"""
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.settings = ai_game.settings
        
        #Load the alien image and set its rect attribute
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/alien.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        
        #Start each new alien near the top left of the screen
        self.rect.x = self.rect.width
        self.rect.y = self.rect.height
        
        #store the aliens exact horizontal position
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)
        
    def update(self):
        """Move alien to the right or left"""
        self.x += (self.settings.alien_speed * self.settings.fleet_direction)
        self.rect.x = self.x
    
    def check_edges(self):
        """Returns true if alien is at edge of the screen"""
        screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
        if self.rect.right >= screen_rect.right or self.rect.left <= 0:
            return True

# settings.py

class Settings:
    """A class to store all settings for Alien Invasion."""
    
    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the game's static settings."""
        
        # Screen settings
        self.screen_width = 1200
        self.screen_height = 800
        self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)
        
        #Ship settings
        self.ship_speed = 3
        self.ship_limit = 3
        
        #Bullet settings
        self.bullet_speed = 2.0
        self.bullet_width = 3
        self.bullet_height = 15
        self.bullet_color = (60, 60, 60)
        self.bullets_allowed = 3
        
        #Alien settings
        self.alien_speed = 1.0
        self.fleet_drop_speed = 10
        #fleet_direction of 1 represents right; -1 represents left
        self.fleet_direction = 1
        
        #How quickly the game speeds up
        self.speedup_scale = 1.1
        
        self.initialize_dynamic_settings()
    
    def initialize_dynamic_settings(self):
        """Initialize settings that change throughout the game"""
        self.ship_speed = 1.5
        self.bullet_speed = 3.0
        self.alien_speed = 1.0
        
        self.fleet_direction = 1
        
        #Scoring
        self.alien_points = 50
    
    def increase_speed(self):
        """Increases speed settings"""
        self.ship_speed *= self.speedup_scale
        self.bullet_speed *= self.speedup_scale
        self.alien_speed *= self.speedup_scale

#game_stats.py

class GameStats:
    """Track statistics of alien invasion"""
    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        """Initialize stats"""
        self.settings = ai_game.settings
        self.reset_stats()
        self.game_active = False
        
    def reset_stats(self):
        """Initialize stats that can change during the game"""
        self.ships_left = self.settings.ship_limit
        self.score = 0

#ship.py

import pygame

class Ship:
    """A class to manage the ship."""
    
    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        """Initiatilize the ship and set its starting position."""
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.settings = ai_game.settings
        self.screen_rect = ai_game.screen.get_rect()
        
        # Load the ship image and get its rect.
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        
        #Start each new ship at the bottom center of the screen.
        self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom
        
        #Store a decimal value for the ships horizontal position.
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)
        
        #Movement flag
        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_left = False
        

        
    def update(self):
        """Update the ship's position based on the movement flags."""
        #Update the ships x value, not th erect.
        if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
            self.x += self.settings.ship_speed
        if self.moving_left and self.rect.left > 0:
            self.x -= self.settings.ship_speed
        
        #Update rect object from self.x.
        self.rect.x = self.x

    
    def blitme(self):
        """"Draw the ship at its current location."""
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
        
    def center_ship(self):
        self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)
```

Comment: This is just a guess, but in your _ship_hit function you have "self.stats.game_active_= False" . Should that be "self.stats.game_active =False"? it looks like you might have an extra underscore at the end

Comment: I owe you my life, that was it. You think you've checked every character but then that happens. Thank you so much, I'm not sure when I would've noticed that.

Comment: Wonderful! I am glad that solved your issue. Don't forget to click the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer. This marks the answer as "accepted", and will help to indicate that the question has been solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Converting my comment to an answer

original comment:

"This is just a guess, but in your _ship_hit function you have `self.stats.game_active_= False`
Should that be
`self.stats.game_active = False`?

it looks like you might have an extra underscore at the end"